# Pass values in sql 'IN' using batch file

Tags: sql, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a job which will call an SQL file and export it in csv. How can I pass values for 'IN' in sql query which is being called in batch file.

For example : 
SQL `select name from student where roll_no in () named user.sql`
This sql is being called in `sqlplus -S usr/pwd @user.sql`.

How can I pass values in sql file. Please advise.

Comment: Perhaps the person who voted this down could explain why.

Comment: I don't know, but I upvoted it to counteract the downvote. I think it's a good question from a novice user that wants to learn!

Comment: @DanBracuk I downvoted because I thought it showed next to no research effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
select name from student where roll_no in ('your Value') named user.sql
```

Comment: is there any way that I can give values in external file and call that file in user.sql ??

Comment: Are using sql server or Oracle if you are using oracle i don't know